# Detect event when user clicks the program on the taskbar?

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

I want to know which event is firing in wpf window form if the user click my application on the taskbar to minimize or maximize the application. I just tried Activated and Deactivated events and, it's not working.I mean these events are triggering so many times. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`Window.StateChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.statechanged.aspx) event is fired after your window is minimized, maximized, or restored.

However, if the window is simply obscured by other windows, clicking on the taskbar will bring it to front without changing its size. This will trigger the `Activated` event, but not `StateChanged`.

Comment: This Activate event is triggering like 9 or 10 times when I click on the taskbar. I just want to trigger only once sth lick clicking on the button.

Comment: @DAvid: That's what you have to work with. Show us your code and provide more details if you can't achieve your aim.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stateChanged` event of the window. It fires when window maximized and minimized i think it solves the problem.

hope this helps.

Comment: this event doesn't fire if you only click the application icon on the task bar.